# Swift UI detect start and end of gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I want to use a long press gesture and detect when the user has been holding for 1 consecutive second, and I also want to detect when the user lets go of the screen. Currently the onChanged detects when the gesture begins and the onEnded fires after 1 second. So I can use the onEnded to detect when the user has been holding for 1 consecutive second. But how can I know when the user lets go?

```
Color.blue
                .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.0)
                    .onChanged { _ in
                        UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                    }
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, `LongPressGesture` ends when the time interval required to trigger it has elapsed, instead of when the user has lifted their finger. Therefore, it is unsuitable for detecting the finger lifting.

I would use a `DragGesture` instead. Its `onChanged` is called when the gesture starts, and its `onEnded` is called when the finger lifts. We can record the start time in `onChanged`, and end time in `onEnded`, and hence how long the user has been pressing down.

```
@State var touchDownTime: Date?
@State var impactTrigger = false

var body: some View {
    Color.yellow
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged({ value in
                    if touchDownTime == nil {
                        touchDownTime = value.time
                        impactTrigger.toggle()
                        print("Started")
                    }
                })
                .onEnded({ value in
                    if let touchDownTime,
                       value.time.timeIntervalSince(touchDownTime) >= 1 {
                        impactTrigger.toggle()
                        print("Ended")
                    }
                    self.touchDownTime = nil
                })
        )
        .sensoryFeedback(.impact(weight: .light), trigger: impactTrigger)
}
```

Note that I have changed it to use `sensoryFeedback` to create the haptic feedback. If you are targeting an older version than iOS 17, using `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` is fine too.

Note that unlike a `LongPressGesture`, which doesn't trigger when the user moves their finger too much after pressing down, `DragGesture` is still recognised if the finger moves. If this is undesirable, use the `value.translation` property to determine whether the finger has moved too much.

```
@State var shouldCancel = false
...
.onChanged({ value in
    ...
    let threshold: CGFloat = 10 // decide a threshold
    if hypot(value.translation.width, value.translation.height) > threshold {
        shouldCancel = true
    }
})
.onEnded({ value in
    if let touchDownTime,
       !shouldCancel, // <----
       value.time.timeIntervalSince(touchDownTime) >= 1 {
        impactTrigger.toggle()
        print("Ended")
    }
    self.touchDownTime = nil
    shouldCancel = false
})
```